# Geofences for a route in Android

Tags: android, geolocation, android-geofence

Having a route as a set of locations, I want to know when the user deviates from it using geofences. At the moment I'm creating a geofence for each location on the route, but it doesn't really cover the route in a sensible way (example below).

I want to replace this:
[image: Wrong geofencing]

With something such as this:
[image: Right geofencing]

Currently, I can only think of manually calculating locations on the route every X meters and adding more geofences, but it seems more like a band aid rather than a good solution.

Is there a way to achieve something similar to the second photo without many many small geofences, or is this the only way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Robert's answer, I eventually used a similar method in [Google Maps Android API utility library](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/) named `PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath()`.

Comment: I have the similiar problem . I want to track whether user is inside or outside the fence (that means polygon) around the route . Does this method `Polyutil.isLocationOnPath()` checks for the same or only check whether the user is on the path .

Comment: `isLocationOnPath` is for polylines only. Check out the method 'containsLocation' instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you try to solve this with normal geofences you will ended up with a lot of geofences overlap to cover all the polygon.

If I would have to solve it, I would probably go with a defined polygon and checking for the user to be in/out of it.

You can check the following library to accomplish this pretty easily.

https://github.com/sromku/polygon-contains-point

1) Setup your coordinates polygon

`Polygon polygon = Polygon.Builder()
        .addVertex(new Point(1, 3))
        .addVertex(new Point(2, 8))
        .addVertex(new Point(5, 4))
        .addVertex(new Point(5, 9))
        .addVertex(new Point(7, 5))
        .addVertex(new Point(6, 1))
        .addVertex(new Point(3, 1))
        .build();`

2) Check if the user is inside/outside of it on every location change

`Point point = new Point(4.5f, 7);
boolean contains = polygon.contains(point);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe I've missed something, but should I download and compile the library in order to use it? I didn't find anything simplified in the instructions.

Comment: Well that's the easy part, you can just download the three files. No fancy dependencies, all math ;) Although to be fair, I do not know the exact precision of this library. I overall i found it pretty accurate and fast when I used it.